# Ruby Watir - getting NoMethodError: undefined method 'start' on a newly installed PC

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm new to Ruby so this might be a really dumb question.  But we have this code working on an existing Ruby install PC.

```
def usr_OpenURL(strURL, strBrowserType)

    if strBrowserType == "IE"
        # Open Browser at the specified URL and Maximise
        browser = Watir::Browser.start(strURL)
        browser.waitForIE
        browser.bring_to_front
        browser.maximize
        sleep($nSleepTime)
    elsif  strBrowserType == "Chrome"

        browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
        browser.goto strURL
        sleep($nSleepTime)
    else
        puts "No Known Browser is Declared"
    end
    return browser

end
```

However installing the same version of Ruby on my pc and running the code is returning the error:

```
undefined method 'start' for Watir::Browser:Class (NoMethodError).
```

So I used irb to play around with it a bit.

If I do:

```
require "Watir"
browser = Watir::Browser.start("http://www.google.com")
```

I get the error, but if I do:

```
require "Watir"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser = Watir::Browser.start("http://www.google.com")
```

then its ok.  It opens a new browser window at that url as expected.

Comparing the PCs I can see different versions of the watir, and watir-webdriver gems are installed - so not sure if something changed between versions.

The person who wrote this ruby code is no longer here - so I can't ask them why they're not doing a .new and Goto for IE.

Any ideas would be appreciated :) Thanks!

Update:
I found this in watir-classic 3.2.0 gem. Thinking maybe that is the culprit.

*Watir::Browser is now a class instead of a module - beware if you're monkey-patching.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is likely occurring because the new PC is using Watir 4.0.0, where as the previous PC was using a Watir 3.x version. The recently released Watir 4.0.0 has logic for directing usage between the watir-classic gem and the watir-webdriver gem.

I believe that the gem is not determined until you do `Browser.new`. After that, the gem is loaded and if it is the watir-classic gem you will have the methods such as `Browser.start` and `Browser.attach` (as these do not exist in watir-webdriver).

A possible solution, if you are only using IE is to directly require the needed gem. So do:

```
require 'watir-classic'
```

instead of

```
require 'watir'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem in watir 4.0. I've opened up an issue for that https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/5 - hopefully i will fix it soon :)

Comment: The issue is fixed, I have just checked.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `Browser#start` is just a shortcut for `Browser#new` and `Browser#goto`. I do not know what is causing the error, but it should be perfectly safe to replace

```
browser = Watir::Browser.start(strURL)
```

with

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
browser.goto strURL
```

Comment: Accepting this answer as its the approach I've decided to go with - but Justin's answer mentions why it was happening.. Damn this not being able to pick two. :)

Comment: Then upvote all the answers that helped, and accept the one that helped the most.

Comment: Ended up needing to do both in the end (use this code, and require watir-classic) has we had a reporting module that stopped working. (But I did upvote all answers and accept one)